# Sublime Text 3 not available from Dash despite posessing a .desktop file

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash, .desktop, sublime-text

After installing Sublime Text 3 .deb file the package description said something along the lines of "This is to be run on the terminal". 
So I said to myself, "No problemo Sublime, I will create a .desktop file for you... Huh?"

As it appears, Sublime Text already has a .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` but I do not understand why Dash can't see it when searching?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
```

Did I mention I'm a Linux noob?

Comment: I had this issue as well. Can't remember how I fixed it though. Let me check my .desktop and see if I can recall what I did.

Comment: @AndroidDev That would be most helpful. Thanks Dev.

Comment: I have Ubuntu in a dual boot with Windows 7, and unfortunately I can't reboot at the moment since I'm rendering a video in Win7, so I'll get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: @AndroidDev Alright, no worries.

Comment: Hi cnic, you probably (well, actually certainly) have a sublime `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`. Remove it, log out and back in, for the local one will always overrule the global one.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Looked in the location mentioned but I cannot see a sublime `.desktop` file.

Comment: Could you drag the global `.desktop` file to the launcher and click on it? If it works, there is *some* local `.desktop` file, representing ` Sublime`.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Dragged the file onto the launcher, clicked it, and it worked. Still does not show in the search?

Comment: You *must* have a local `.desktop` file, referring to Sublime.  Could you run: `grep sublime ~/.local/share/applications/*` and see what it sais?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Screenshot [local directory](http://i.imgur.com/Gh76sZI.png?1)

Comment: Posted screenshot before I saw your new comment. Ran the command and nothing was returned.

Comment: Then what gives: `grep sublime /usr/share/applications/*`

Comment: @JacobVlijm [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/RtrfxUd.png?1) is it the opt directory?

Comment: Silly question, but did you already log out/in after installation? The only file, referring to Sublime is the correct one...

Comment: You are absolutely spot on with that assumption! Logged on again and it is there. Big thanks to you @JacobVlijm ! Why would you need to log off in this particular instance? Doesn't do that for other installs.

Comment: Would you mind if I made it an answer? Kind of a "what to do if..."? Log out/in can make Unity reconsider where all files are sometimes.

Comment: Go for it buddy.

Comment: In my case I double-clicked the desktop file at /usr/share/applications/sublime_text.desktop and got an error. Looking at the file, I noticed it linked to /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text, when my actual executable was at /opt/sublime_text_3/sublime_text.

Comment: Personally, I deleted the entry and then re-added it using the exact same config in OP's question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### What to do if an application does not show up in Dash, or cannot be launched from Dash after you installed it?

It can happen that you installed an application, you are sure the application is represented by a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`, but it either does not show up or the icon in the launcher doesn't do what it is supposed to do.

1. *Log out and back in*
   Although an application *should* show up immediately after installation, incidentally, new `.desktop` files are not found immediately. Logging out and back in makes sure Unity is forced to re- read the directories `~/.local/share/applications` and `/usr/share/applications` for valid launchers.
2. *Test- check the global `desktop` file*
   If that does not solve the issue, browse to `/usr/share/applications` and drag the corresponding `.desktop` file on to the launcher and click on it.
   If the application is launched correctly, you can be pretty sure you have a local `.desktop` file, representing the application, in `~/.local/share/applications`. 
   Since local `.desktop` files overrule their global version, the local one is most likely incorrect or outdated.
   *To find it*, open a terminal and run:

   ```
   grep -iR <application> ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```

   where `<application>` is (of course) the name of the application.

   Remove possible local versions, log out and back in.

   If the application does *not* launch correctly, your global `.desktop` file is incorrect, which is highly unlikely, but if so, it can have several causes.

#### Explanation

If you have duplicated launchers (`.desktop` files), representing the same application, `Unity` picks the local one on log in. During a session, this does not change normally, *unless* you force Unity to use a specific launcher by dragging it on to the Unity Launcher.

This is usually the fastest and most reliable way to both check the validity of the global `.desktop` file, *and* detect the existence of local versions, rather then digging through `~/.local/share/applications`.